# How to upload swift project by xcode 7.3 using application loader

Tags: arrays, swift, xcode

When i upload app using application loader i got bellow error. In error show add distribution profie but i already added distribution profile then also give error. please help me for upload swift project using xcode 7.3 on iTunes

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Make a archive with your distribution profile and export a IPA file in your system.After that open a application loader and drag and drop that IPA file.